# Парсинг веб страницы

Tags: html, парсер

Нужно с единственной html страницы, куда можно попасть, введя свой логин/пароль, периодически (раз в час) считывать текст. Вот кусок кода:

```
 <div class="friendbox__name">
     43826<br>
     Владимир Н.В.
 </div>
*********************
 <div class="friendbox__name">
     85901<br>
     Денис С.Г.
 </div>
```

Надо забрать данные в виде

```
43826 Владимир Н.В.
85901 Денис С.Г.
```

с целью занесения в базу данных.
Чем проще всего сделать, посоветуйте. В интернетах куча инфы, просто запутался уже.

Comment: какой хотя бы язык программирования используете?

Comment: Да любой, чем проще? С++, PHP, JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего на JS, так как не нужно мануально парсить HTML: он отличается от XML не закрытыми тегами и придется делать велосипед. Чекнуть можно [тут](https://jsbin.com/samocet)

```
<div class="friendbox__name">
     43826<br>
     Владимир Н.В.
 </div>
 <script>
     const symbols="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя1234567890.<>".split('');

     (function(){
         const arr=document.getElementsByClassName("friendbox__name");
         for(let i=0;i!=arr.length;i++){
             const line = arr[i].innerHTML.toString().split('').filter(char=>symbols.includes(char.toLowerCase())).join('').split("<br>")
             console.log({
                 num:line[0],
                 fio:line[1]
             });
         }
     })();
 </script>
```

Comment: а что насчет авторизации, про которую написал автор?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ судя по меткам автора, вопрос в контексте вытягивания информации из CMS вида WordPress через добавление плагина с инъекцией JS кода.